# how to display alert popup based on a value

Tags: javascript, popup, alert

I have a drop down list like `nothing, name1, name2, name3, name4 and etc,...`  When I select `nothing` only the alert popup should display where as popup should not display when I select others.

Any ideas?

Comment: show us what you have tried. we have many ideas but we would like to konw what is your idea behind your requirement?

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#dropdown_change").change(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("dropdown_change").value == "nothing"){
    alert("nothing");
    $("#popup").css("display", "block");
    }
     });
   });
```

```css
#popup{
    position: fixed;
    margin:auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<form id="myform">

   Select a value from the list:
 
   <select id="dropdown_change">
      <option value="name1">name1</option> 
      <option value="nothing" id="open-popup">nothing</option>

      <option value="name2">name2</option>
 
      <option value="name3">name3</option>
  
      <option value="name4">name4</option>
   
 
</select>
</form>
<div id="popup"> POP UP</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is some what looking good. I will cross check and let you inform Mr. Atiq

Comment: @KSKumar can you please upvote the answer if you find it correct?